# How to Convert a Linear Model to Conv1 in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am new to Pytroch and I cannot transform Keras models that I have in my mind in to it.

I have a really simple linear model in Pytorch as follows:

```py
class linear_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output, activation=nn.ReLU):
        super(linear_model, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(26, 26),
            activation(),
            nn.Linear(26, 26),
            activation(),
            nn.Linear(26, 26),
            activation(),
            nn.Linear(26, 26),
            activation(),
            nn.Linear(26, 26),
            activation(),
            nn.Linear(26, 26),
            activation(),
            nn.Linear(26, 6)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.net(x)
        return out
```

I want to use Conv1d instead of a linear layer. Something like this:

```py
class resnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output, activation=nn.ReLU):
        super(resnet, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(26, 64),
            activation(),           
            nn.Conv1d(64, 64, kernel_size=5,padding=2),
            activation(), 
            nn.MaxPool1d(3,stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.Conv1d(64, 32, 3,padding=1,stride=2),
            activation(), 
            nn.MaxPool1d(3,stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.Linear(32, 6)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.net(x)
        return out
```

The first Conv1d needs an [64,64,6] input and I provide it an [10,64] input (the batch size is 10).

To summarize, I have an array [1,26] and I want to feed into the network, increase its size to [1,64], then reduce it to [1,6] at the end.

I'm conflicting with the concepts of Keras and Pytorch. How should I correct the problem?

Edit:

I have changed the model, and now it's working. After all, I have no clue what's going on there. Here is the new one:

```
class custom_model(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, output, activation=nn.ReLU):
    super(custom_model, self).__init__()
    self.net = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(num_features, 64),
        nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
        nn.ReLU(),           
        nn.Conv1d(1, 64, kernel_size=5,padding=2),
        activation(), 
        nn.MaxPool1d(3,stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.Conv1d(64, 32, 3,padding=1,stride=2),
        activation(), 
        nn.MaxPool1d(3,stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.Conv1d(32, 6, 1),
        activation(),
        #nn.Conv1d(6, 6, 1)
        nn.Linear(32, output),
        nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(6, 1),


    )

def forward(self, x):
    x = torch.unsqueeze(x,1)
    out = self.net(x)

    return out
```

And, changed the way I calculate the loss to make it compatible:

```
outputs = model(inputs)
outputs_squeezed = torch.squeeze(outputs)
loss_value = loss(outputs_squeezed, y_train)
```

The model I devised is not necessary correct (I mean, the concept behind it). I just cannot figure out what is happening. To make it clear, I cannot understand what are the input and output of the Conv1d and how I can connect them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are passing is that of single-point data. The difference between data of shape `[B,N,L]` for 1D tensors and `[B,N]` for single-point tensors is critical for the application of N-D convolutions (in this case B is batch size, L is sequence length, and N is feature depth).

To solve this for your case, just add a dimension to your data so that N=1, because at the moment you do not have a third dimension. However, according to your question I am unsure if you're missing the batch (first) dimension or the feature (second) because you say you provide both, but not simultaneously? Nevertheless, I think this can be entirely amended by:

```
input = input[:,None,:]
```

Or

```
input = torch.unsqueeze(input,1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made some changes according to your suggestion. But, I still cannot understand it correctly. Would you please tell me what's happening there? I have edited my code, you can look it again

Comment: You need to understand the basics of what you’re trying to do. Think of how pytorch handles images: tensors of shape `[batchsize, channels, height, width]`; how it handles audio: `[batchsize, features, timesteps]`; and how it handles data points: `[batchsize, features]`. These correlate to the dimensionality of the data, 2D (images), 1D (audio), and 0D (data points) which make them suitable for 2D convolutions, 1D convolutions, and linear layers (ignoring broadcasting), respectively. There is no way to apply these layers (in the simple case) if your data is not formatted correctly.